# ASP.NET MVC4 - validation based on model generated by entityFramework of multiple forms

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

in my very first asp.net mvc4 project,i'm trying to apply some validation tests on my four forms in the same page.Each form allows me to create a different type of project in my table(dataBase),so i'm using the same model generated by entity framework and for validation i used a partial class having the same name of my generated model and i've inserted data annotation such as required with error messages.My problem is when i submit one form leaving a required field empty,the appropriate validation error message is shown for all my forms and not only the one i submitted.Please can someone tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: in order to avoid such problem just take multiple forms on view..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `RequiredAttribute` on (say) property `Name` and its null on postback, a validation error is added for that property. If you inspect the html generated for the form, you will see something like this (assuming your using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)`) which acts as a placeholder for any validation error message associated with `Name`

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Note the `..data-valmsg-for="Name"..`. Since your rendering 4 identical forms using the same model which generates 4 inputs for property `Name`, there will be 4 corresponding validation errors.

Your approach in rendering 4 identical forms does not make sense since you can only post one back. I suggest you consider using a view model that includes a property for `ProjectType` and render a DropDownList so the user can select the project type. Then only one form is required, and when submitting, get the selected `ProjectType` and use this to make whatever decisions you need to save the data.

Comment: i understand what you said about validation errors,but i don't think i'm able to use one form,because in my case one ProjectType has some fields that the other ProjectType doesn't have,so i found myself obliged to make four forms.i changed my approach to use 4 models each one represents a ProjectType(i used TPH inheritance) and  i planned to create a partial class with data Annotation for each model(in a viewModel),but then my partial classes where not used,and when i tried it with the project partial class,displayName works but not the Required dataAnnotation,don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If each project type has different properties/attributes, then they definitely should be separate models, but more importantly separate actions and views. You should not be trying to combine these in one view with 4 forms (use separate views for CreateProjectType1, CreateProjectType2, ..)

Comment: yess,but i'm obliged to combine them in one view because our client asked for it.

Comment: Then create a view model which has 4 properties, one for each project type, `public ProjectType1 Project1 { get; set; }` etc, then render the inputs as `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project1.Name)`, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project2.Name)` etc so the the controls have distinct names and distinct associated validation controls.

Comment: i've already done that, but the required dataAnnotation is not working while display dataAnnotation is.I created my 4 ProjectType entities as objects inheriting from Project entity that has a table in my dataBase

Answer (score 0):

Just structure your View in this way :-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
{
  ..........
  ..........
  <button type="submit">Update this stuff</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form2" }))
{
  ..........
  ..........
  <button type="submit">Update this stuff</button>
}
```

**In above example when you submit "Form1" model validations associated with "Form1" will fire and same case for "Form2".**

Comment: my view is already structured that way,all my four forms have different ids.don't know where the problem is!!

Comment: @sassa92...strange this should not happen just check your beginform tags their opening and closing brackets and each beginform should have their separate submit button inside beginform form braces..

Comment: all my forms are considered as one form,because when i fill a field in one form the same field in the other forms is filled with the same value.i'm thinking maybe this happend because i used partial class,i'll try my previous version of the project without it and i'll let you know.

Comment: @Exception..actually my previous project works just fine without the partial class and validation stuff don't know what's wrong.maybe i should change my method of validation,but the only way i could find is the partial class method,do you have any idea ??

Comment: @sassa92...no i have never used partial class in mvc..we just make simple model classes for views and they work great..!!!

Comment: @Exception..ah okk,but in my case since entity framework is generating my models i'm not able to do simple model classes.thank you for your help.